# Query to fetch On hand Available to Reserve Oracle Fusion?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-apps

Available_to_reserve = nvl(TR_QTY,0)- (nvl(TR_QTY_B,0)+ nvl(TR_QTY_C,0)

I was using this logic with this query, but it's not working anymore, when I check the UI the value is wrong for some items

```
SELECT SUM(transaction_quantity) AS TR_QTY_C
FROM
INV_ONHAND_QUANTITIES_DETAIL
WHERE inventory_item_id = :INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND organization_id = :P_ORG_ID
AND subinventory_code IN (SELECT SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME
FROM
INV_SECONDARY_INVENTORIES
WHERE organization_id =:P_ORG_ID
AND reservable_type = '2')

SELECT SUM(RESERVATION_QUANTITY)AS TR_QTY_B
FROM INV_RESERVATIONS
WHERE inventory_item_id = :INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND organization_id = :P_ORG_ID

SELECT SUM(transaction_quantity) AS TR_QTY
FROM
INV_ONHAND_QUANTITIES_DETAIL
WHERE
inventory_item_id = :INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND organization_id =:P_ORG_ID
```